# Delete the line leading with non-numeric data and insert the text before a specific text format with Python

Tags: python, text

I have a file with thousands of lines of the format

```
unwantedtext1 
unwantedtext1
50779       1   52476   52475   52481   52485
50780       1   52485   52481   52480   52484
.....
.....
unwantedText2
50614  1.8837812e+001  7.0057003e+000  1.6900000e+002
52200  4.6960466e+001 -2.5497744e+000  1.4950614e+002
.....
.....
unwantedtext3
unwantedtext3
```

In the next step I have to add the text wantedText1 in the beginning of file and wantedText2 when the field 2 becomes a real number and not an integer anymore. so that output would be

```
wantedtext1 
wantedtext1
50779       1   52476   52475   52481   52485
50780       1   52485   52481   52480   52484
.....
.....
wantedText2
50614  1.8837812e+001  7.0057003e+000  1.6900000e+002
52200  4.6960466e+001 -2.5497744e+000  1.4950614e+002
.....
.....
wantedtext3
wantedtext3
```

These wanted text could be either echoed directly or could be input from other other. The data is space delimited and not tabs delimited.

Any suggestions using python?

Comment: open the input file for read, open the output file for write.  Write the text you need to beginning of the output file, then read each line of the input file, make any changes necessary to the line before writing it to the output file.  Close the files.  If you have any specific problems with any aspect, post your code and ask a question.

Comment: what's 'wantedtext3'?

Comment: @cdarke, i am totally new to PYTHON. I have worked with MATLAB and in recent past just learned some LINUX but now everything is being shifted to windows, hence I thought to learn PYTHON for scripting, as a beginner I can put here Hello world nothing more unfortunately. You can see I never posted anything about PYTHON before. peace. You can -1 a beginner!

Comment: @NizamMohamed it is the text that I want to enter at the end of the file. A string basically

Comment: Hamad:  that's OK, we all have to start somewhere, it's just that you need to think out the steps before you start to code.  I see you use `awk`, and you could do this using that language, the steps are the same.  If you work out the steps you need first, its then just a case of reading the Python manuals to find how to code each step.  Python (not PYTHON) is of course much more powerful than `awk` (or `gawk`).

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag to reflect if we have seen real number.

```
seen_real_number = False
with open('file_name') as in_file, open('output.txt','w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('wantedtext1\nwantedtext1\n')
    for line in in_file:
        if not line.strip():
            out_file.write(line)
            continue
        fields = line.split()
```

If the line has only one field or first field is a non-digit,skip the line.

```
        if len(fields) == 1 or not fields[0].isdigit():
            out_file.write(line)
            continue
```

Here, the line has more than one field and the first field is a number. To check if the second field is a real number, I call `int`, it will throw an exception if second field is a real.

```
        try:
            int(fields[1])
        except ValueError:
```

Here, we have seen a real number. Toggle `seen_real_number` and write 'wantedtext2'.

```
            if not seen_real_number:
                out_file.write('wantedtext2\n')
                seen_real_number = True
            out_file.write(line)
        else:
```

No exception has ocurred now, the second field is a non-real. Toggle `seen_real_number` flag. Because if we encounter a real number again we can write 'wantedtext2' again.

```
            if seen_real_number:
                seen_real_number = False
            out_file.write(line)
    out_file.write('wantedtext3\nwantedtext3\n')
```

I don't modify the read lines so that output file should have exact formatting as input file.

Comment: thanks, but my data is not tabs seperated, it is space seperated and my format should remain the same as before. you code changes it to  single spaced.